# SQL Server 2012: set a column to only use a single case?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to tell SQL Server 2012 to store both `A` and `a` as `A` (or both `A` and `a` as `a`) for some given column such that every insert statement does not need to have `UPPER()` in it?

Comment: Is the column case sensitive? If it isn't, you shouldn't need `UPPER()` anywhere. If it is, no, you would need to use a trigger (to just fix it) or a check constraint (to raise an error).

Comment: ... and if it's just a "presentation" thing then i'd handle it in the "presentation" layer.

Comment: If your data's collation is accent insensitive, then you should get what you want.  (Usually, because there are characters that look like the same character to you and me, but not to other persons.)

Comment: Maybe a computed column would be an option.

Comment: @ZabadakGalorex Then you'd need *two* columns.

Comment: @swasheck  Large legacy application that only somewhat follows a separation of concerns architecture.  It isn't worth chasing down every single spot the data is presented.  Also, the data in question are alphanumeric case insensitive codes, so special characters aren't a concern.

Comment: How many different insert statements could there possibly be? Why isn't there a single insert statement that is invoked via a stored procedure? Fixing that once is much better than having a trigger that will fire forever.

Comment: @Lawtonfogle so are you saying that your presentation layer is SSMS/TOAD/SqlDbx/SQLCMD/OSQL or something of the sort? Otherwise, I don't see why it can't be handled in a presentation layer, regardless of how separate (or not) it may end up being. I'm not saying rewrite everything in MVC (or whatever the scriptkids are advocating these days), I'm saying to use whatever is retrieving the data to modify the case of the data.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Fixing the insert/update sprcs would be the fall back.  My previous comment was about when it is rendered, as the fallback is still technically doing presentation work in the data access layer.

Comment: I know what your previous comment was about (and my point would still apply there, since there shouldn't be all that many queries for *retrieving* data, either), but in the question you say "every insert" - if it's more than one, why?

Comment: @swasheck  Think 3 dozen pages using 3 dozen different select statements or sprocs.  That is 3 dozen locations where we would have to modify the display.  Add in other applications using (but not inserting/updating) the same data that would also have to be modified.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  There shouldn't be, but there are, and that is beyond my authorization to fix.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this silently using an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_table_name
  ON dbo.table_name
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT dbo.table_name(col1, col2, col_you_care_about)
    SELECT col1, col2, UPPER(col_you_care_about)
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

If you want to raise an error, you can use a `CHECK` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.blart(a VARCHAR(32));

ALTER TABLE dbo.blart ADD CONSTRAINT ck_col
  CHECK (CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), a) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(32),UPPER(a)));
GO

INSERT dbo.blart(a) VALUES('A'); -- succeeds
GO

INSERT dbo.blart(a) VALUES('a'); -- fails
```

Result:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "ck_col". The conflict occurred in database "dba", table "dbo.blart", column 'a'.

But I have to agree with @swasheck above - what difference does it make how it's stored? If you just want it *displayed* in upper case, do that at rendering time, not storage time.

Comment: Or have a computed column for it that shows the UPPER/LOWER version, and read that instead of the source column.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, in order to emphasise a really important data management point - any aesthetic qualities of your data should be handled at the presentation/reporting/glass level of your IT application - don't let SQL do hard work that it simply doesn't need to do!

Another example I see often is including the "£" or "$" symbol in every row of data to show currency values - why, unless there is a need to differentiate the data at that level, would anyone do that? Get the application or report to do it!